# what is the type of image have to be for colour checker detection

Tags: python, opencv, colors

When I tried to use a color detection library of color project for an image opened by OpenCV, I thought I would have to convert it to RGB. But when I did that, I received an incorrect result of color checker segmentation. In the original example of color checker segmentation example, the image opened using:

```
COLOUR_CHECKER_IMAGES = [
    colour.cctf_decoding(colour.io.read_image("IMG_1967.png"))
   ]
for image in COLOUR_CHECKER_IMAGES:
    plot_image(colour.cctf_encoding(image))
# Detection
SWATCHES = []

# for image in COLOUR_CHECKER_IMAGES:
for swatches, colour_checker, masks in detect_colour_checkers_segmentation(
        image, additional_data=True):
    SWATCHES.append(swatches)
    # Using the additional data to plot the colour checker and masks.
    masks_i = np.zeros(colour_checker.shape)
    for i, mask in enumerate(masks):
        masks_i[mask[0]:mask[1], mask[2]:mask[3], ...] = 1

plot_image(
        colour.cctf_encoding(
            np.clip(colour_checker + masks_i * 0.25, 0, 1)))
```

The images decoded during opening and then encoded to use it for `detect_colour_checkers_segmentation` and to display the result had to encoding the resulted image. These were taking a long time and the calculating results make the result not accurate.

I found that it is better to open image by OpenCV as BGR and use it in `detect_colour_checkers_segmentation` and encoding the resulted image.

Can someone explain to me why this is?

Comment: Please actually show us the results.  Also please consider providing a [mcve].  As it stands your code is not reproducible and your question is at risk of being closed.

Comment: Please share your input and corresponding output images too.

Answer (score 1):

The expectation for the `colour_checker_detection. detect_colour_checkers_segmentation` definition is for the image data to be linear floating-point RGB in range [0, 1].